# ようにしてください Question, Verb + する?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Hello I am learning Japanese right now and was wondering what the difference between these two sentences is (or if the latter is even correct?)

水を飲むようにしてください。

水を飲むするようにしてください。

I was doing a quiz and the question was what does it mean to say "Please drink water" and I thought the second answer might have also been correct? Thanks in advance I hope you can understand my question!!

Comment: 「飲むする」 is not grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

You can never use "verb + する" in any situation.

飲むする, 買うする, 学ぶする, 死ぬする, 壊すする.
They're all incorrect.

You can say "熟語 + する" like 購入する, 学習する, 死亡する, 破壊する instead; though 飲む doesn't have a common 熟語, so you can't use this way.

Answer (score 1):

Only the first sentence is correct. 飲む is already a verb, and it can directly connect to ように. 水を飲むする is an invalid combination of two verbs, almost like "drink do water".

(If you know suru-verbs like 勉強する, the kanji part is not a verb on its own, so する is necessary to make it act as a verb.)